# change latlng in google map directions api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, directions

i working with google map directions api in android application.when i send two Location to google api it return route between both but LatLng is changing and no one send me.Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement LocationListener to locate user's device GeoCode.

That will take some effort. You could refer the demo I made here [mClima](https://github.com/cuongmanhvo162/mClima)
The listener for location change was implemented in MainActivity. Remember to declare permision in AndroidManifest

Comment: I use from LocationListener but location that return from google direction it is different with location that i send